# fbShare in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer

Can anybody suggest a good method for creating a facebook share implementation for my application.

I have created the test account and API key for the facebook developer site...

I need to implement in such a way that,when the fbshare button is clicked,a particular content(dynamic content) should be posted as a status link in the corresponding linked facebook account...

Apart from the fb developers,i need some other way of implementing it...

Suggestions expected...(possibly better results expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/

it may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use this method in your code in facebook handler class

```
public void postToFBWall(final String message, final String image){

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    String descripton = "This is the plain text copy next to the image. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.";
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", message);// message to be posted on facebook wall
                    parameters.putString("link", image);//link of image to be posted on facebook wall
                    parameters.putString("name", "My wish");// name of link
                    parameters.putString("description", descripton);// description of you post
                    String response1 = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
                    Log.v("facebook response", response1);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        };thread.start();

    }
```